# Tensor does not throw exception on out of range index

Tags: c++, eigen

Here I create a tensor of 1 by 1. I try to access and set a number at (1,0) and (0,1) which are both out of range indices. I am expecting to get an assertion or exception error.

```
Eigen::Tensor<int,2> data(1,1);
auto n1 = data(1,0);
data(0,1) = 1;
```

But it runs just fine. But if I try to do the same thing with a matrix of the same shape, I get an assertion error as expected.

```
Eigen::Matrix<int,1,1> matrix;
auto n2 = matrix(1,0); // Signal: SIGABRT (Aborted)
matrix(0,1) = 1; // same error here
```

Checking the the Eigen headers, I see that the tensor implementation checks the indices like this (though I have no clue how it works):

```
bool checkIndexRange(const array<Index, NumIndices>& indices) const
{

  // ...

  return
    // check whether the indices are all >= 0
    array_apply_and_reduce<logical_and_op, greater_equal_zero_op>(indices) &&
    // check whether the indices fit in the dimensions
    array_zip_and_reduce<logical_and_op, lesser_op>(indices, m_storage.dimensions());
// m_storage.dimensions() evaluates to {1,1}
}
```

The matrix implementation checks the indices with this code:

```
eigen_assert(row >= 0 && row < rows()
          && col >= 0 && col < cols());
```

I checked the Eigen documentation [here](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md?fileviewer=file-view-default#markdown-header-data_type-tensorindex0-index1) but it doesn't say anything about out of range behavior. My question is: why do I not get an out of range assertion error when I access out of range numbers in a tensor?

Edit: My Eigen version is 3.3.90

Comment: What compiler flags are you using? Asserts are not usually checked when `-DNDEBUG` is defined.

Comment: @AviGinsburg `-DNDEBUG` is not defined.

Comment: Then please supply an [MCVE] so that people can understand your issue. Also, do you have the same issue with a non-beta version of Eigen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tensor module seems to do only `eigen_internal_assert` here, instead of `eigen_assert` as the Core module does. To activate internal assertions, you need to compile with `-DEIGEN_INTERNAL_DEBUGGING` -- this will likely slow down Eigen significantly, though (depends on what you are doing, of course).

Comment: Thank you. [Defining `EIGEN_INTERNAL_DEBUGGING`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html) works as well.

Comment: Defining `EIGEN_INTERNAL_DEBUGGING` is what `-DEIGEN_INTERNAL_DEBUGGING` does (with g++ or clang++) ...